# Use material ui svg icons as background image

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, google-material-icons

Can I use `@material-ui/icons` svg images as background of other elements.? Tried the below code but didn't work.

```
import CarIcon from '@material-ui/icons/DriveEtaRounded';

const carIcon = <CarIcon />

function Cover(){
  return (
    <div
        className={classes.cover}
        style={{ backgroundImage: 'url('+ carIcon+')' }}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using SVG as background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185434/using-svg-as-background-image)

Answer (score 10):

`@material-ui/icons` are React components and if you open their source, they contain only SVG data that are encapsulated in `<svg>` tag using a utility function. However you can simulate background-image behaviour by using them directly and a bit of styling:

```js
import CarIcon from '@material-ui/icons/DriveEtaRounded';

function Cover(){
  return (
    <div style={{position: 'relative', width: '200px', height: '100px'}}>
      <CarIcon style={{position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0, width: '100%', height: '100%'}} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is an example but it will work as long as the parent element has its dimensions set by other content. You can also simulate `background-size: cover` behaviour by adding `preserveAspectRatio='xMidYMid slice'` to the icon component (default value corresponds to `contain`).
An added benefit of this approach is that the icons are still SVGs and can be further styled or animated.

Answer (score 1):

Based on an example from the MUI docs relating to custom switches, you can set the backgroundImage property to an Mui icon using the following format:

```
backgroundImage: `url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
  <path fill="${encodeURIComponent('#fff',)}" 
  d="M4.2 2.5l-.7 1.8-1.8.7 1.8.7.7 1.8.6-1.8L6.7 5l-1.9-.7-.6-1.8zm15 8.3a6.7 6.7 0 11-6.6-6.6 5.8 5.8 0 006.6 6.6z"/>
</svg>')`,
```

It's messy because you can't just use CarIcon, you need the actual svg path (the d attribute in above example).  To get the d value of the svg I wanted to use, I just found the icon's file in node modules (e.g node_modules > @mui > icons-material > DriveEtaRounded.js):

DriveEtaRound.js:

```
"use strict";

var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = void 0;

var _createSvgIcon = _interopRequireDefault(require("./utils/createSvgIcon"));

var _jsxRuntime = require("react/jsx-runtime");

var _default = (0, _createSvgIcon.default)( /*#__PURE__*/(0, _jsxRuntime.jsx)("path", {
//
// ----  d value here \/
// 
  d: "M18.92 5.01C18.72 4.42 18.16 4 17.5 4h-11c-.66 0-1.21.42-1.42 1.01l-1.97 5.67c-.07.21-.11.43-.11.66v7.16c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5S6 19.33 6 18.5V18h12v.5c0 .82.67 1.5 1.5 1.5.82 0 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5v-7.16c0-.22-.04-.45-.11-.66l-1.97-5.67zM6.5 15c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5S5.67 12 6.5 12s1.5.67 1.5 1.5S7.33 15 6.5 15zm11 0c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zM5 10l1.27-3.82c.14-.4.52-.68.95-.68h9.56c.43 0 .81.28.95.68L19 10H5z"
//
// ----  d value here /\
// 
}), 'DriveEtaRounded');

exports.default = _default;
```

So your end result should be:

```
backgroundImage: `url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
  <path fill="${encodeURIComponent('#fff',)}" 
  d="M18.92 5.01C18.72 4.42 18.16 4 17.5 4h-11c-.66 0-1.21.42-1.42 1.01l-1.97 5.67c-.07.21-.11.43-.11.66v7.16c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5S6 19.33 6 18.5V18h12v.5c0 .82.67 1.5 1.5 1.5.82 0 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5v-7.16c0-.22-.04-.45-.11-.66l-1.97-5.67zM6.5 15c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5S5.67 12 6.5 12s1.5.67 1.5 1.5S7.33 15 6.5 15zm11 0c-.83 0-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5s.67-1.5 1.5-1.5 1.5.67 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5zM5 10l1.27-3.82c.14-.4.52-.68.95-.68h9.56c.43 0 .81.28.95.68L19 10H5z"/>
</svg>')`,
```

make sure you use d="... and not d:"...