# Trying to use MUI icon component in style property

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I'm trying to use a MUI icon component inside of the `background-image` css property. I am not having any luck.

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import ArrowForwardIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowForward';

const DivStyled = styled('div')`
  background-image: url(${ArrowForwardIcon}) /* this obviously isn't working */
}
```

`

Comment: url accepts an url in css, not a react component. You're mixing css with js code so obviously it doesn't work. What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: Trying to display the MUI SVG icon as the background image for the custom styled div.

Comment: I've pivoted to a different approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62009252/use-material-ui-svg-icons-as-background-image

Comment: This seems to be the feasible approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62009252/use-material-ui-svg-icons-as-background-image

Comment: There is another approach. You can place the div and icon inside a parent div of ```position: relative```, make the icon taking full height and width of the parent, and set the position of the div to ```absolute```. It automatically goes on top of the icon.