# Can an encoded SVG for background-image be imported from a separate file?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG file:

**myIcon.svg**

```
<svg>.....</svg>
```

I want to use it in my css:

```
   .body {
       background-image: url(../myIcon.svg);
   }
```

since an svg needs to be encoded for it to work as a background-image, that leaves me with something like this:

```
.body {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,***<here place encoded svg>***");
}
```

Is there a way to store the encoded svg in it's own file for maintainability?  Since it's not in html tags, I'm not sure how save it to it's own file or if it's even possible.

Comment: "since an svg needs to be encoded for it to work as a background-image,"  uhm, **what?** - (by "encoded" I assume you mean Base64-encoding), and if so, then **no, that's entirely incorrect**. You don't even need to use Base64 encoding with `data:` URIs ([it's complicated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)), but when using `url()` in CSS with `http`/`https` URIs you can refer to _any_ valid image resource that the UA supports.

Comment: oh I got that from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185434/using-svg-as-background-image .  The top solution mentions: "To use it at css background-image you gotta encode the svg to address valid string. I used this tool (name: URL Decoder—Convert garbled address)"

Comment: The post you're referring to only concerns `data:` URIs (and even then, isn't entirely accurate, as in _many_ (but not all) cases Base64-encoding is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put some hours in investigating which characters are **not allowed** in a `data:image/svg` URI
Many encoders convert `<` and `>`, but those are valid.

- Load your **external SVG** file and replace all invalid characters
- Create a new `<style>` element with the `background-image`

Wrapped in a modern Web Component so it totally does not matter **when** the script is executed

⚠️ `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` **must** be present in the SVG file; it is not required when you **inline** SVGs in modern browsers.

```html
<svg-import-background src="//svg-cdn.github.io/red.svg" selector="#container"></svg-import-background>
<svg-import-background src="//svg-cdn.github.io/yellow.svg" selector="div > h2"></svg-import-background>
<svg-import-background src="//svg-cdn.github.io/blue.svg" selector="pre"></svg-import-background>

<style>
  body { font:16px Arial; color:beige }   h2   { color: black }
</style>

<div id="container">
  <h2>Web Component &lt;svg-import-background&gt;</h2>
  Inject external SVG file into CSS background-image
  <pre>
&lt;svg-import-background ATTRIBUTES:
                                   src="PATH TO SVG FILE"
                                   selector="Element selector"
  </pre>
</div>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-import-background", class extends HTMLElement {
    async connectedCallback() {
      let svg = await (await fetch(this.getAttribute("src"))).text();
      svg = svg.replace(/\>[\t\s\n ]+\</g, "><"); // replace all BETWEEN tags
      svg = svg.replace(/#/g, "%23");
      svg = svg.replace(/"/g, "'");
      this.innerHTML = `<style>${this.getAttribute("selector") || "body"}{`+
        `background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,${svg}")`+
      `}</style>`;
    }
  })
</script>

<svg viewBox="0 0 8 8"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="gold"></rect></svg>
```

## Re: `encodeURIComponent`

Yes, you can replace all **3** `replace` statements with:

`svg = encodeURIComponent(svg);`

The difference is what is injected in your HTML code.

The **3** `replace` statements injects:

`<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'><rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='%23f00'></rect></svg>`

`encodeURIComponent` injects:

`%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%208%208%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Crect%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22100%25%22%20fill%3D%22%2300f%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E`

It is up to you which one you want to **debug**

Comment: correct; ``encodeURIComponent`` is shorter and probably (I have never tested it) faster. But its a pain to debug. See addendum above. I preferred the readable version in my [SpriteMeister experiment](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/create-svg-spritesheet-animations-with-1-template-literal-string-3hee)

Comment: Again, untested, I presume the fully encoded version is **slower** in **de-** coding.