# SVG file as a background

Tags: html, css

```
body {
      background-image: url('./circle.svg');
}
```

straight up not working for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using SVG as background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185434/using-svg-as-background-image)

Comment: Despite the terrible quality of the question (please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] in particular)... one thing to be aware of (which isn't obvious) is that paths in CSS files are relative the position of the **file** and NOT the page in which the file is referenced

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the SVG is in the right directory? try placing it in the same directory as your `style.css` and adding `background-size: cover;`

If your SVG is in the same directory as your css this should work:

```
body {
    background-image: url('circle.svg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

If your SVG is in the parent directory of your style .css make sure the `url()` has `../` infront of it.

Comment: I tried as you said but it didn't work... My SVG file is in the same directory as my HTML. I am using the <style> tag in HTML instead of actually using CSS.

Comment: Can you see the CSS happening in inspect element? Try testing this by adding a background-color to your css