# How to add svg to button in react native

Tags: react-native, svg

How to use svg image like background in button in react native?

for example how to put this image to button:

```
import Svg, {Path} from "react-native-svg";

export function FillPerson({ size }) {
    return (
        <Svg width={size} height={size}>
            <Path d="M3 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4-1 1-1 1H3zm5-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z" fill="#fff"/>
        </Svg>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185434/using-svg-as-background-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your SVG to `TouchableHighlight` or `TouchableOpacity` with `View` container:

```js
function Button({ onPress, size }) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={{ width: size, height: size }}>
        <Svg width={size} height={size}>
            <Path d="M3 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4-1 1-1 1H3zm5-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z" fill="#fff"/>
        </Svg>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

Comment: There is also neccesary viewBox <Svg width={size} height={size} viewBox="0 0 16 16">

Comment: And better TouchableOpacity